# Can schwa be made in the word, calm?

Tags: pronunciation

Can the schwa[ə] sound be made even in the word **calm**, while which is being said in the sentences?

Comment: What is wrong with this question? If you thought it was a no-brainer, you should have said so, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The schwa is short and unstressed, and the word *calm* is neither, even when it's within a sentence.

> The boat was motionless on the calm sea.
>   A calm descended on the crowd.

Pronunciation in [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/calm): /kɑːm/

Comment: Perhaps OP was wondering whether it could be pronounced /ka:ləm/.

Comment: Ah. Well the question could be edited for that. It is the case that some words are pronounced that way in Northern Ireland. Not sure about *calm*, but definitely with *film*.

Comment: Many people pronounce final /-lm/ as /-ləm/. Depends on their syllable construction rules, which have a tendency to get idiosyncratic because of individual habits. I.e, it's not necessarily a geographic trait; it may be social or individual.

Comment: I think it is always better to avoid giving a categorical answer without an authoritative reference. There can be exceptions to general "rules".

Comment: @Kris: Added a reference for you.

Comment: I've don't believe I've ever heard any speaker of British English pronounce the "l" in "calm".

Comment: @ColinFine I’m from the upper Great Lakes area, but for me, the word *calm* sounds like the start of *call me a cab*, and just truncates with the *m*. There is no other difference.  So it is /kɔlm/ when speaking carefully, or perhaps /kɔːm/ in rapid speech.  It never reduces to /ɑ/ or /a/; that would be a completely different vowel. It is much more rounded here, at least where I am from. People who pronounce it like *come* always confuse me a great deal.